# Problem connecting WPA2 PEAP MSCHAPV2. Handshake failure on client hello

Tags: debian, networking, wpa-supplicant, wpa2-eap

I am having terrible trouble connecting to my school WPA2 PEAP MSCHAPV2 wifi. I've tried Network Manager, wicd and connman and most recently I am connecting via wpa_supplicant.

The school does not require a CA certificate. I know this is ill-advised but I don't have responsibility for that.
The connection works immediately in Windows, with which I dual boot, so I know the hardware is working.

I have included dmesg output, wpa_supplicant.conf, wpa_supplicant -dd debug output, and relevant wireshark packets in this Google doc:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HawjC5BS5BHBb5zxFUcWR4TInAhZXVDdt7ReGW0LiKg

The problem occurs after the Client Hello when the AP disconnects because of a handshake failure.

I have been working for days on this and have tried the system-ca-certs=false workaround. Any pointers would be gratefully received.

**Update:**

I notice that Wireshark says that the client hello is TLS version 1.0. I believe this is deprecated now? Does anyone know how to force the use of TLS 1.1 or 1.2 in the handshake? I will keep researching.

This post suggests that there are servers that will drop the connection if the client doesn't specify a TLS version higher than 1.0.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29314/what-is-the-significance-of-the-version-field-in-a-tls-1-1-clienthello-message

**New update:**

Looking at the Wireshark packets from my Ubuntu laptop, which connects successfully, I can see that server negotiates a cipher suite (tls_rsa_with_3des_ede_cbc_sh) that Debian doesn't support. I originally thought this could be the problem, but oddly, when Windows connects the server negotiates a different cipher suite that Debian does support.

Comment: Would you mind being more specific? I don't see how there are three protocol directives. Perhaps you missed the fact that all but one of them are commented out. I will change the file to clarify.

Comment: As you prevented people copying from your doc, I suggest you post the relevant tidbits in the question. I wont be losing time trying to circumvent that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion. I have enabled copying and highlighted what I think are the most relevant parts in red, although someone who knows more than I do may see other parts as relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try a more minimal WPA Supplicant configuration. The one I use is given here: https://chiraag.nataraj.us/wireless/index.php (specifically under the WPA-EAP subsection)

Almost certainly, the issue is with the WPA Supplicant config.

Comment: That looks like a great article. Thanks. I'll go through it and post any results. I've tried totally minimal wpa_supplicant configs and I know pretty well now what the defaults are. The reason that I think it's almost certainly not a wpa_supplicant problem is that I have configured my Debian machine in exactly the same way as my Ubuntu laptop, both using Network Manager, and Ubuntu connects and Debian doesn't. Anyway, I'll keep hammering away.

Comment: I would also try using Wicd or systemd-networkd + wpa_supplicant instead of Network Manager - I know I used to have a ton of problems back when I used it.

Comment: I've tried everything with respect to network manager, wicd, connman and wpa_supplicant on its own. I get a handshake failure at the client hello stage. I have added details to the question.

Comment: Which cipher suite does Windows use? You might be able to force that option in the WPA Supplicant configuration.

Comment: If they have a common cipher suite they should find it, no? In any case, I don't see a way of forcing the cipher suite in WPA Supplicant.

Comment: You can force the cipher suite with the `pairwise` and `group` options in `wpa_supplicant.conf`. But yes, if it's a common cipher suite, the defaults should "Just Work"™ Can you try getting rid of every key in `wpa_supplicant.conf` besides `ssid`, `key_mgmt=WPA-EAP`, `eap=PEAP`,`identity`, and `password`? And if you're sure the configuration isn't the problem, I wonder if Debian and Ubuntu build it differently...if it's not too much of a hassle, maybe you can try building `wpasupplicant` yourself to see if that fixes it?